# Is there any transition intent listener?

Tags: android, android-intent, listener

Is it possible to handle animation of intent transition?

Actually I am possible in my project to click on button (which opens new intent) and fast click back - so that code in activity second is executed but I am still in on first screen.
I would like to wait till new screen shows and then execute code.

So far I was trying with handlers and async tasks but it wasn't good move.
I am not able dig in xml animation code, it's very big. My playgoround is only in two activities.

---

So far I found link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.TransitionListener.html So far I don't know how to use it..